# Django staticfiles_dirs not working correctly

Tags: django

I'm working with this website http://fotokluczniok.pl/ now.
If You press F12 You will see the staticfiles do not work correctly.

Here is my seetings.py code:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    '/home/fotoklu/fotokluczniok/static/',
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')
```

Here is urls.py code:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Project structure: [CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDWGE.jpg)

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you running `collectstatic` on the server? And how are you writing the URLs that use `static` in the templates?

Comment: Everytime when i change i'm collecting them. Using in templates:  {% load staticfiles %} {% static 'css/account.css' %}

Comment: Is it running correctly in the developments server? Your `STATIC_ROOT` is one level above the static path in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. And if it's correctly configured you shouldn't need the hard-coded path in /home/fotoklu.

Comment: So how it should look like ?

Comment: Ok i set `STATIC_ROOT` to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`

Comment: But it  still doesnt work fine

Comment: Well, it depends on where the folder is relative to the settings, but based on the project structure I think `STATIC_ROOT` was correct and you should use that for both settings (i.e. `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')`).

Comment: Actually, forget about it, what I wrote before doesn't make sense, it shouldn't be the same for both settings, because the root is where things will be collected. What you could do is hard code the paths on the server, just to establish where things should be, and then try to understand why they aren't being placed in the right directory.

Comment: How to hard code them ?

Comment: Write the full path to the folder containing the collected static files in `STATIC_ROOT`. That should make the site work. Then you need to understand how to generate it dynamically.

Comment: Ok i will try :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to change something about the static files in the urls.py file. And also delete the variable STATIC_ROOT. In general your code in Settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

I also had this problem. It helped me.
NOTE: Always restart the server after changes in settings.py